# Why was this a split pot? PLO8

Tags: omaha, showdown, omaha-hi-lo

Please see the image attached. I don't understand why I didn't win here.

My hole cards: 7c Ah 7d 7h
His hole cards: 10d 3c 10h 8s

Cards Dealt:5d,As,9h,2s,2c

From what I understand:
I made two pair (As,Ah,2s,2c,7h)
He made two pair (10d,10h,2s,2c,As)

Why did I not win? Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks in advance

[image: Split pot shown after showdown]

Answer (score 3):

Your analysis is correct; your high hand (AA227) is better than your opponent's (TT22A).

My best guess as to why this was a split pot is that you were playing Omaha Hi-Lo, not standard PLO. In Omaha Hi-Lo, half the pot is awarded for the best 'high' hand and the other half for the best 'low' hand (if there is one).

There are a few variants of Omaha Hi-Lo and exact rules can vary but you can find an introductory explanation [here](https://www.pokernews.com/poker-rules/omaha-hi-lo.htm).

In this case, your opponent has a qualifying low hand of A2358. You have no qualifying low hand (because only unpaired cards of value 8 or lower count). Your opponent therefore has the better low hand.

So because you win the 'high' hand and your opponent wins the 'low' hand, the pot is split.

Comment: You're spot on. PLO8 is another name for PLO Hi-Lo